# How to have state in a an ansible callback plugin

Tags: ansible

I want to make a ansible callback plugin, that hides sensitive data in  the ansible output. There is a suggestion on how to do it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/754860/how-can-i-reduce-the-verbosity-of-certain-ansible-tasks-to-not-leak-passwords-in):

```
from ansible.plugins.callback.default import CallbackModule as CallbackModule_default
import os, collections

class CallbackModule(CallbackModule_default):
    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'stdout'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'protect_data'

    def __init__(self, display=None):
        super(CallbackModule, self).__init__(display)

    def hide_password(self, result):
        ret = {}
        for key, value in result.iteritems():
            if isinstance(value, collections.Mapping):
                ret[key] = self.hide_password(value)
            else:
                if "password" in key:
                    ret[key] = "********"
                else:
                    ret[key] = value
        return ret

    def _dump_results(self, result, indent=None, sort_keys=True, keep_invocation=False):
        return super(CallbackModule, self)._dump_results(self.hide_password(result), indent, sort_keys, keep_invocation)
```

Now this example hides "password". I now want to make the word, that are hidden configurable at runtime of the playbook.

Can I somehow give the plugin a state (a list of words to hide) and modify it at the runtime of the playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `self.words_list` inside `__init__` to some default value.
Then inside `...on_task_start` and `...on_handler_task_start` check for some specific variable and modify your `self.words_list` accordingly.

You can take a look at how persistent properties to collect statistics are used in [profile_tasks](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.2/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/profile_tasks.py) callback plugin.